# Make checkbox in chrome look like one in IE

Tags: css

The checkbox in IE and chrome looks different.

**Chrome**

[image]

**IE**

[image]

From above images you can see the difference. I want checkbox in chrome looks same as in IE.

I tried **webkit-box-shadow** and other similar css properties but no luck. Can you please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple way is just to add `-webkit-appearance: none;`.  But you will need to then style the checkbox to match what you want.  Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzdcbyc5/

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>

.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.checkbox:checked {
    background: url(http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox/images/5/57/Very-Basic-Checkmark-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20131125154354) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. this is almost close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "filter: brightness" which doesn't work in IE so it doesn't affect IE but can make the chrome checkbox and radio buttons look almost white with something like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    filter: brightness(1.2);
}

/* Set disabled back to grey */
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled,
input[type="radio"]:disabled {
    filter: brightness(0.9);
}
```

Comment: This is so much better than everything others mentioned in every thread. Is there any problems with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your needs? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dovdWv

Basically, I used `-webkit-appearance: inherit;` to reset the checkbox to initial state, and used the `:after` pseudo-element to create your check mark.

Tested only on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Google Chrome works on different rendering engines (Layout engine ). webkit-box-shadow works in google chrome and latest Safari which uses webkit layout engine.

```
.squaredFour {
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 18px auto;
}
.squaredFour label {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.squaredFour label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 8px;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.squaredFour label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.squaredFour input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}



<section title=".squaredFour">
    <div class="squaredFour">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" checked />
      <label for="squaredFour"></label>
    </div>
 </section>
```

http://jsbin.com/saxunaqiqi/1/edit

This will work in Google Chrome and IE 10+ browsers.