# Browser Neutral checkbox needed IE vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I've been reading a lot of online resources to define browser neutral check boxes, I must find a way to define this style in common.css for check boxes in IE& chrome which is used by aspx,ascx,etc pages

As long as enabled boxes are white and disabled boxes are grey, I will be happy (enough) with them

Please help, shed some light.

So far I have tried many diff styles but not working..
[Make checkbox in chrome look like one in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627961/make-checkbox-in-chrome-look-like-one-in-ie)

below is almost close what I was looking for but its not setting grey color when checkboxes are disabled.

```
.mycheckbox {
 position: relative;
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
 border: 1px solid #111;
 background: #fff;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -appearance: none;   
  }
 .mycheckbox:checked {
  background: url(http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox/images    /5/57/Very-Basic-Checkmark-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20131125154354)      no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: You're probably better off following the concept of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30628210/1028949) where they pretty much hide the checkbox and use a `span` for the rendering instead of trying to change the appearance of the checkbox directly. Either way, you'll want to use `.mycheckbox:disabled` to target disabled elements.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you so much.

Comment: checked:checkbox appear white in IE11 where as in Chrome it appear as the background theme(blue). how to fix this blue to white check box appearance I set the color in .checked{CSS} not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make checkbox in chrome look like one in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627961/make-checkbox-in-chrome-look-like-one-in-ie)